# access object property from object method in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have something like

```
var foo = function(arg){
  var something = {
    myPropVal: "the code",
    myMethodProp: function(bla) {
      // do stuff with mypropval here
      alert(this) // => DOMWindow
    }
  }
}
```

is this possible? can i access the contents of myPropVal from within myMethodProp given the

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sure you can

```
var foo = function(arg){
  var something = {
    myPropVal: "the code",
    myMethodProp: function(bla) {
      // do stuff with mypropval here
      alert(this) // => DOMWindow
      alert(this.myPropVal);
    }
  }

  alert(something.myMethodProp());
}
foo();
```

Comment: So actually `this` is not the DOMWindow.

Comment: What `this` is depends on the context of how the function was invoked. So you might be safer using `something` explicitly.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can, below is an example.

```js
obj = {
  offset: 0,
  IncreaseOffset: function (num) {
    this.offset += num
  },
  
  /* Do not use the arrow function. Not working!
  IncreaseOffset2: (num) => {
    this.offset += num
  } 
  */
}

obj.IncreaseOffset(3)
console.log(obj.offset) // 3
```

Comment: This answer deserves some love. The arrow function, for whatever reason doesn't work in this case - excellent spot! ++1

Answer (score 4):

In the context of an anonymous function used as property in an object, `this` refers to the object and can be used to access other properties.

```
const robin = {
  firstName: 'Robin',
  lastName: 'Wieruch',
  getFullName: function () {
    return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  },
};

console.log(robin.getFullName());
// "Robin Wieruch"
```

Answer (score 2):

You might have to reference it as `something.myPropVal`.